# Rain radar image noise reduction and cleanup

Tags: machine-learning, python, image-recognition, noise

An [application](https://geshem.space) that I am building is plotting rain radar images on map. The images are transparent PNGs that are sourced straight from the local meteorological service.

As can be seen in the example, the images have two types of noise I'd like to get rid of:

1. Directional interference (can be seen at around 11 o'clock on the image below)
2. General noise (small dots that are not real rain clouds)

A human eye can easily see what the "real" clouds look like when viewed as an animation.

What are some recommended methods to clean up this image that reduce as much noise as possible? References to algorithms and tools (Python, prefereably) alike would be appreciated.

Methods can include cleaning up each image separately, or using previous frames as context.

[image: Rain radar example animation]

Comment: Here is something to consider: weather formations are chaotic. So we do not have the math to model chaotic systems future behavior, so you will be laying a linear solution over a non-linear space. Long way of saying that error will be high, as you cannot tell true data from noise. My guess is that the best you can do is a high pass filter, bur it will remove true data as well. For the radar line, you may be able to do something using amplitude and time dimensions.

Comment: I'm not attempting anything perfect here, just trying to reduce noise. Throwing away the low density data is probably good enough for my use case. 'True data' is a loose term here anyway since I have no control over the original radar tuning parameters.

Comment: awesome, under those requirements I would write a high pass filter for the first sprint.  That seems to be the task that will deliver the most value.

Comment: @davmor sounds perfect, any libraries I can use for that?